# Initialising empty interface vars where all members are functions

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a type which requires a function callback and am getting stuck with variable initialisation. Type Terminal.New() requires type Repeater which has a SetPacketFunc callback. This is defined in Terminal.New as such:

```golang
//Package dmr
type Repeater interface {
    Active() bool
    Close() error
    ListenAndServe() error
    Send(*Packet) error

    GetPacketFunc() PacketFunc
    SetPacketFunc(PacketFunc)
}
//Package terminal
func New(id uint32, call string, r dmr.Repeater) *Terminal {
    t := &Terminal{
        ID:       id,
        Call:     call,
        Repeater: r,
        slot:     []*Slot{NewSlot(), NewSlot(), NewSlot()},
        accept:   map[uint32]bool{id: true},
    }

    r.SetPacketFunc(t.handlePacket)
    return t
}
```

In my code I'm initialising an empty Repeater type variable:
`var r dmr.Repeater` then passing that as an argument to to `t := terminal.New(123,"test",r)`. However at runtime I'm getting a `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` at `terminal.New` line in my code.

How do I define the Repeater type properly if all of its members are functions?

Answer (score 1):

When you define the variable `r`, it is initialized to the zero value, which is, for an interface, nil. So when you call `SetPacketFunc`, the receiver for that function is nil, giving you that error.

You have to pass a concrete repeater, or a repeater interface pointing to a concrete implementation of repeater:

```
var r = SomeRepeaterImpl{}

func f() {
   term:=terminal.New(123,"test",&r)
}
```